# Test first character in string give segmentation fault

Tags: c

I'm trying to give my program a command line argument, strip the first character and turn the remaining string into an int. But I get a segmentation fault when I do the test with `if (argv[i][0] == 'w')`.

```
$ ./program w10
Segmentation fault
```

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <argp.h>
#include <python2.7/Python.h>


/* If this flag is nonzero, don’t handle the signal right away. */
volatile sig_atomic_t signal_pending;

/* This is nonzero if a signal arrived and was not handled. */
volatile sig_atomic_t defer_signal;

void
huphandler (int signum)
{
  if (defer_signal)
    signal_pending = signum;
  else
    exit(0);
}


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        signal(SIGHUP, huphandler);

        int i;
        int wait = 0;
        char *args[argc+3];
        args[0] = "mypy.py";
        for (i=0; i<argc; i++) {
                if (argv[i][0] == 'w') { // Here's where the problem is
                        memmove(argv[i], argv[i]+1, strlen(argv[i]));
                        wait = strtol(argv[i], NULL, 10);
                }
                else {
                        args[i+1] = argv[i];
                        printf("%s\n", args[i+1]);
                }
        }
        argc = i + 2;
        FILE *file;
        Py_SetProgramName(args[0]);
        Py_Initialize();
        PySys_SetArgv(argc, args);

        while (true) {
                defer_signal++;
                file = fopen(strcat(getenv("HOME"), "/mypy.py"), "r");
                PyRun_SimpleFile(file, "mypy.py");
                Py_Finalize();
                defer_signal--;
                if (defer_signal == 0 && signal_pending != 0)
                        exit(0);
                if (wait > 0) sleep(wait);
                else exit(0);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to shift the values of argv[i] by one (and trying to write what may be (almost certainly is) readonly memory) rather than just incrementing argv[i]?

Comment: Yes, I have changed it to `argv[i]++;`. I just wasn't sure. It still fails though.

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <string.h>`, which is needed for the `strtol()` and `memmove()` and `strlen()` and `strcat()` functions.  the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>` which is needed for the `exit()` and `getenv()`  functions

Comment: an array of args[] needs to have the final entry be a NULL pointer.  Suggest: after `args[ argc+3]` insert: `for ( i=0; i < (argc+3); i++) { args[i] = NULL; }` so will automatically have a NULL entry at the end of the array of char* entries in `args[]`

Comment: suggest: replace the two lines: ` memmove(argv[i], &argv[i][1], strlen(argv[i])); wait = strtol(argv[i], NULL, 10);` with the line: `wait = strtol(&argv[i][1], NULL, 10);`

Comment: @user3629249 I'm sorry, I solved this shortly after posting. I'll post an answer, but it's trivial. It had to do with skipping list indexes, because the if increments the counter but doesn't fill the array, you see?

Comment: for this line: `args[0] = "mypy.py";` to work properly, needs to be a pointer to static storage, not to readonly memory.  Suggest: `static char *pgmName[]= "mypy.py";  args[0] = pgmName;`

Comment: when calling the system function: `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 4):

I highly doubt that the problem is there, this

```
fopen(strcat(getenv("HOME"), "/mypy.py"), "r");
```

on the other hand is very very wrong.

The standard forbids modifying the pointer returned by `getenv()`<sup>1</sup>, instead you should use a temporary buffer, this should do it

```
FILE *file;
char path[PATH_MAX]; // Include <limits.h>
int result;
const char *home;
home = getenv("HOME");
if (home == NULL)
    return EXIT_FAILURE; // Problem, `HOME' env variable not found?
result = snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/mypy.py", home);
if ((result < 0) || (result >= (ssize_t) sizeof(path))
    return EXIT_FAILURE' // Very unlikely to happen, BUT CHECK PLEASE.
file = fopen(path, "r")
if (file == NULL) // Please always check ...
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

This would presumably cause *Undefined Behavior* and it means that you can't expect a given behavior, so you can't expect the rest of the program to work correctly.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Excerpt from the [c11](/questions/tagged/c11) standard explaining the issue</sub>.

> **7.22.4.6 The `getenv` function**
>
> 4. The `getenv` function returns a pointer to a string associated with the matched list member. The string pointed to **shall not be modified by the program**, but may be overwritten by a subsequent call to the getenv function. If the specified name cannot be found, a null pointer is returned.

The quote is from the C11 Standard Draft N1570, I highlighted the bold part in order to make it clear where it says that you can't modify the pointer.